# Make animation like apple landing section

Tags: reactjs, animation, scroll, gsap

Here is a link(https://www.apple.com/airpods-3rd-generation/)
I want to make animation like the landing section. How is it possible? is it made with GSAP library?
Please share your Opinions.
[image]